# crystal report - uses subreport, has to get data from 2 different database in one command

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport, multiple-databases

I have installed crystal reports 2011 for .net 4.0. I create crystal report using visual studio. I use command to get data. the command gets data from 2 database. the 2nd database has same user and password as the one provide during creating command. only name and content of 2nd database is different. name of the 2nd database is passed as parameter to the command.

Everything works fine. but when i change the database connection settings from backend the reports give error [

Error in File temp_7eda6175-1a02-42ab-b517-bfef5dc33ba6 10524_3948_{C8BE61CE-D420-4BBB-8BFD-67B238688671}.rpt:

Failed to retrieve data from the database.

Details: [Database Vendor Code: 207 ]

]

but when i manually verify database, and run the project the report works again.

my problem is i need to run this report on different client system. each time in each machine i cant verify database manually.

I tried crystalreportobject.verifydatabase(). but that results in an exception

[log on failed]

login credentials are correct. i have double checked

please help

1. i have assigned login credentials to all subreport table in loop.
2. i tried assigning both credentials to all tables